# How to iterate through all the fields of an object

Tags: parse-platform

I have an object that has about 23 columns. Is there a way to iterate through each column automatically? Rather than specifically selecting each column using `.get("COLUMN_NAME")` ?

Thanks guys.

Comment: `parseObject.attributes`

Comment: I'm sorry. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's say a `Class` `A` -- with `fields'` `id`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `a`, `b`, `c` and `obj` is an instance of `A`.

`obj.attributes` is an object which hold `a`, `b`, `c` and `id`, `createdAt`, `updateAt` are properties of `obj`.

The following is an example to show all fields' name except special field (`id`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`) in web console.

```
Object.keys(obj.attributes).forEach(function(fieldName) {
    console.log(fieldName);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To be more simple :

`object.get('COLUMN_NAME')` is equivalent to `object.attributes.COLUMN_NAME`

So if you do a `console.log(object.attributes)` you will have a JS Object as example :

```
{
"cheatMode":true
"createdAt":Tue Oct 30 2018 10:57:08 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale) {} (this is a JS Date object)
"playerName":"Sean Plott"
"score":1337
"updatedAt":Tue Oct 30 2018 12:18:18 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale) {} (this is a JS Date object)
}
```

With all attributes and their values.
That's all.

---

Full example code of ParseServer Query

```
const GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
const mainQuery = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
mainQuery.equalTo("cheatMode", true);
mainQuery.find().then(async (response) => {
    response.map(function(object){
        console.log(object.attributes)
        // Will log for example :
        // {
        // "cheatMode":true
        // "createdAt":Tue Oct 30 2018 10:57:08 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale) {} (this is a JS Date object)
        // "playerName":"Sean Plott"
        // "score":1337
        // "updatedAt":Tue Oct 30 2018 12:18:18 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale) {} (this is a JS Date object)
        // }
    })
});
```