# How to include all keys in single query to Parse object

Tags: parse-platform

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Order");
    query.equalTo("objectId", orederId);
    query.include("price");
    ...
    query.include("keyName");
```

Is it possible in Parse to include all existing object's keys in single query if we don't know keys names?

Assume that object was created dynamically and there is no info about it's keys names, but we need to get this object with all included pointers.

Comment: If you make sure all fields are pointer and just want to get all fields name then the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947656/how-to-iterate-through-all-the-fields-of-an-object/27951354#27951354) might work around.

Comment: no.several filed are defenetly strings, as objectID, etc

Comment: And the main difference is that we DON"T HAVE object yet, we are just knowing its id and are going to query it

Comment: I can't get what you said. Did you mean you just save the objectId string not pointer?

Comment: It was the answer to your comment:"If you make sure all fields are pointer" - no, I am not sure that all fields are pointers, because several fields of the object can be simple strings, Dates, etc..

Comment: Okay, then you could check whether a field is pointer by `typeof obj.attributes[fieldName] === 'object' && 'className' in obj.attributes[fieldName]`.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but the problem is that i don't have an instance of "obj", i just received its id from another method and want to retrieve this object with all its fields included..

Comment: Oh, now I get it. I'm afraid that you could not do it if object was created dynamically. As far as I know Parse did not provide a way to include pointer without given fieldname.

Comment: Thanks for your investigation. I think it is really so

Answer (score -1):

Create a subclass for your object and override the query method like this. Put all includeKeys where the comment says. Use the class method initObject to create and initialize your objects.

```
@implementation MyPFObject 

@dynamic objectUUID;
// Other fields
+ (MyPFObject*) initObject
{
    MyPFObject* obj = [self object];
    [obj tlObjectInit];
    // Other initializations
    return obj;
}

+ (NSString*) parseClassName
{
    return @"MyPFObject";
}

+ (PFQuery*) query
{
    PFQuery* query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName: [self parseClassName]];
    // Add includeKeys here
    return query;
}

@end
```

Comment: It is obj c clients code, but I use cloud code and JS for backend logic. Client uses REST api

Comment: I read the question too quickly. Sorry. You could probably use a similar trick in Cloud Code.

Comment: If iOS users see this it will be useful for them. I create a separate module for each class in my Cloud Code to hold before and after_save functions, plus any other class related functions I need.

Comment: Someone put a -1 on this answer. Why? What are you objecting to? What would a better solution be?